# Multivariate distribution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I notice that in scipy, the multivariate distribution is always parameterized with the mean vector and the covariance matrix. I have a problem where the parameterization with a sparse precision matrix (inverse of the covariance matrix) is more appropriate.

Is there any class which would allow me to parameterize it directly with the precision matrix? The number of variables is quite large and I would like to avoid computing the inverse of this sparse precision matrix, if possible.

Comment: What do you want to do with your distribution? Do you just want to sample from it?

Comment: No, I have some updates (used in belief propagation) where I am multiplying and dividing distributions and this has simple updates in terms of precision.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "multiplying and dividing distributions"? If they are parameterized by their mean vectors and precision matrices then you presumably want to express the results of your manipulations in terms of these quantities.

Comment: You might find [these identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Properties) helpful.

Comment: Well, usually in belief propagation you want to "divide out" a marginal distribution, update it and put it back by multiplying it. Anyway, in most cases, it is much better to have the parameterisation with the precision matrix rather than the covariance matrix because the precision is usually much sparser. Also, for many problems, it is much easier to directly construct this sparse matrix. So, this was the reason why I wanted the parameterisation in terms of mean and precision. I guess I will write it myself.

Comment: Well, you'd have to derive the parameters of the new distribution yourself anyway, regardless of whether you have the precision matrix or the covariance matrix. You can't multiply or divide an object returned by `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal()` - you can only sample from it, or evaluate certain static properties such as the PDF.

Comment: It is maybe on option to calculate the density directly. It is quite simple when you already have an inverse covariance matrix. See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Density_function